# avoid getting duplicate records from SOLine and SOLineSplit

Tags: acumatica

I need to get the data from SOLine and SOLineSplit in the report, but when I joined am getting duplicate records, can anyone please suggest to avoid getting duplicates.

Can I go with SQL Views, as i need data for display purpose only not to do any inserts or updates. please suggest.

Comment: Usually this is simply caused by a bad join. If you open the trace window in Acumatica (help->trace) and launch the report, you should have the SQL request in the traces. Inspecting the SQL request will likely reveal which join is the culprit. SQL views are not recommended to use in Acumatica, you'll only make your solution more complex using them.

Comment: Thank you, issue solved and i moved controls from details section to group header section